# AWK if else condition not printing correctly

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

I have the following `testfile.txt`:

```
CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     DP      POS     N_ALLELES       N_CHR   {REF}   {ALT}
chr1    16495   G       C       252     16495   2               2       0.5     0.5
chr1    16719   T       A       189     16719   2               2       0.5     0.5
chr1    16841   G       T       521     16841   2               2       0.5     0.5
chr1    17626   G       A       124     17626   2               2       0.5     0.5
chr1    17697   G       C       63      17697   2               2       0.5     0.5
chr1    19004   A       G       13      19004   2               2       0.5     0.5
chr1    69270   A       G       20      69270   2               2       0       1
chr1    69511   A       G       240     69511   2               2       0       1
chr1    69897   T       C       28      69897   2               2       0       1
```

I am trying to execute an awk command to add a new column based on the information from the text file but the following code is only working on the first conditions:

```
awk '{
    if ($9 == 0.5 && $10 == 0.5 && $7 == 2) {
        print $0"\thet";
    } else if (($9 == 0 && $10 == 0.5 && $7 == 3) || ($9 == 0.5 && $10 == 0 && $7 == 3)) {
        print $0"\t"het2;
    } else if (($9 == 0 && $10 == 1 && $7 == 2) || ($9 == 1 && $10 == 0 && $7 == 2)){
        print $0"\t"hom;
    }
}' testfile.txt
```

And the output that I am obtaining is the following:

```
chr1    16495   G       C       252     16495   2       2       0.5     0.5     het
chr1    16719   T       A       189     16719   2       2       0.5     0.5     het
chr1    16841   G       T       521     16841   2       2       0.5     0.5     het
chr1    17626   G       A       124     17626   2       2       0.5     0.5     het
chr1    17697   G       C       63      17697   2       2       0.5     0.5     het
chr1    19004   A       G       13      19004   2       2       0.5     0.5     het
chr1    69270   A       G       20      69270   2       2       0       1
chr1    69511   A       G       240     69511   2       2       0       1
chr1    69897   T       C       28      69897   2       2       0       1
chr1    120983  C       T       35      120983  2       2       0.5     0.5     het
```

Can someone please explain me why my awk command is not working ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to misquote the string `"het2"` in your second condition. Dito for `"hom"`

Comment: @Cyrus I don't understand why you posted this link when I already followed it.

Comment: @kvantour thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do heed the commenters advice on forming a better question.

In this case, the issue is quoting, you have 
`print $0"\t"hom;` 
which says print the whole line, a tab, then the contents of the variable `hom`, which doesn't exist.

Changing this to `print $0"\thom";` like your first `if` will get the expected results.

Your second `if` has the same issue with `het2`

Also, if you're really using a tab separator you can do `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}` and avoid the need for printing literal tabs, which would let you do things like `print $0,"het"` or `$11="het";print;` which seems more readable.

Comment: thanks. How can I possibly reduce the code more than that when I gave the minimal, complete and verifiable post ? 

I didn't notice this small mistake... I was very tired. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There was sufficient information to get at what you wanted here, just a lot of it unecessary, which is why Minimal was highlighted.  The examples and code were voluminous and the data itself kind of hard to quickly  see what is going on.  The *ideal* question here wouldn't provided perhaps a sample with just the three columns needed, the working if, and the unworking if, with the or's and such removed (so there is one condition to worry about and less need to look at all of the data.)  The idea wit all of this is that in reworking to get that example, youll likely figure it out your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I will be more careful next time. Take care !